# Create iOS ipa file (on Mac)

Tags: rider

I haven't been able to find an archive menu or a way to specify the output as .ipa in the publish menu.  I have my distribution profile set for the project.  And I see on youtrack that this was completed years ago but I haven't been able to find it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?